# ag-grid master-detail mode filtering master

Tags: filtering, master-detail, ag-grid

I am implemting ag-grid master-detail. It works fine overall.

I am facing issue that when I filter master grid, child records doesnot show up on expanding master record.

I don't know if it is a bug of ag-grid or something is missing in my code.

Point to note is that no error is thrown when I see console and still the data is not getting fetched. So where the control should go when expanding master in filtered condition.

I am not posting code as of now as it will be big. Before that of someone can throw light on this issue, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[filtering - groups] Filtering is not working in Master Detail Grids #1324
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1324